# Creating local coordinate system from orthorectified image from drone

Tags: geoprocessing, mathematics, coordinate-system

My plan is to use a drone and pix4d to map an area and produce a top down image. I have some position data that is in its own reference frame / Coordinate system.

My question is what suggestions or tools are out there where I can take the image I created and map it to mimic my coordinate system to my position data.

Id like to have the map of my area, and a plot of the position data super imposed on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for open-source / free software I think you may want to check out the [**opendronemap**](http://opendronemap.org/). This software is actually aiming at producing point clouds and 3D models, but one of the middle steps is creating **orthorectified imagery**, which you may view in a simple browser viewer (where are camera positions shown, like in [OpenSfM project](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM)) or QGIS or any other mapping software.

Another tool for creating 3D models that came into my mind is [Bentley ContextCapture](https://www.bentley.com/en/products/brands/contextcapture). As above, one of the steps to produce the models is to create orthorectified imagery and while viewing the model you can see camera positions. It is a professional and very powerful tool.

As for professional software, I think [Erdas Imagine](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/products/power-portfolio/erdas-imagine) is best recommendation for processing aerial and space imagery. I'm not sure how to plot camera positions, but I guess this software is so powerful it may be possible. You may find older versions created by Leica Geosystems, now it's Hexagon.

Comment: I already have the 2d orthorectified image generate. My question is I have position data, (X,Y) in an non-specific reference frame.

I would like to create a coordinate system out of my 2d, so I can plot the position data over the image.

Comment: Somehow I understood you want to plot the positions of camera while you took the photo - now I see you mean you already have some position data - but can you please explain what do you mean that they are in an 'non-specific reference frame'? You must have some 0,0 reference for coordinates, even if they are in local system. Another thing worth to notice: when you open your orthos in mapping software (e.g. QGIS) you see they are in local reference system, where probably 0 is one of the image corners (depends how you opened it).

Comment: Non-specific meaning not earth based, like lat-long or North East Up/Down. The position data I have is a Cartesian based reference system where the solution came a mix of signals like IMUs. 

My guess is that I can make my coordinate system anything in my top down picture created from my drone. But I am confused at the steps to get there.